# Create a Upnp Server as a android system service, how to set permission for system server so that it can handle http connect requests?

Tags: java, android, upnp

I am creating a service based system on `cybergarage` upnp library. I am successfully able to run this service as part of system server by adding it's entry in `SystemServer.java` file. 
The service gets registered and Upnp server starts sending multicast notify messages. I am using a **control point** application which can discover and **control Upnp devices** present in local network. After the control point discovers my android device(which has Upnp Server running), device serves the description file to control points and goes into a **infinite loop** trying to connect to listening socket from it's **own ip address**. After total number of **open socket limit** is reached it start throwing TOO many Open files error.
These connect requests are **false connect** request sent to Upnp device bind port number. I have put prints to see from which ip these requests are coming after accept.
**QUESTION:**
Is there any special permission which we need to set for system server so that it can `host/accpet/connect` http requests?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the problem myself. This was happening because I forget to add a "/" in upnp device description file. 
I had to add "/" at start of SCPDURL, eventURL and controlURL values.